# discord.js - awaitMessages in textChannel

Tags: discord.js

I would like to do an awaitMessages with discord.js but I have an error. Here is my code:

```
message.channel.send('hello').then(msg => {
                message.channel.awaitMessages(msg, { 
                    max: 1, 
                    time: 10000, 
                    errors: ['time'] })

                    .then(collected => message.channel.send('this is a test'))

                    .catch(collected => msg.delete());
            });
```

Here is my error :

```
if (collect && this.filter(...args, this.collected)) {
                                             ^

TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on [object Object], which is a object and not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like:

```js
message.channel.send('hello').then(msg => {
                message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id, { 
                    max: 1, 
                    time: 10000, 
                    errors: ['time'] })

                    .then(collected => message.channel.send('this is a test'))

                    .catch(collected => msg.delete());
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in `awaitMessages` is the filter function, not a message object.

[docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

Comment: What should I write?